# using stored procedure in IBM I

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have tried for some time but still not able to make a stored procedure on the ibm i. if anyone can write the steps needed.

I have a cl that contains about 8 Query /400. I can have it run at night
but in the event the user wants latest data it would not be.

I have looked at making a group of views but the queries do breaks and totals 
and this is not converting well. i need the exact same data as this bunch of queries makes.

is the idea that i create an sp and link to the cl? or do i code the contents of the cl in the sp? please if you can give me a step 1. 2. 3 would be best.

Comment: "Query/400"? Not exactly fully compatible with stored procedures. The combination doesn't make much sense. If it's "IBM i", we can assume i 6.1 at the earliest. Can you give a little more info on what you expect the SP to return to a user? And what is the result being returned to?

Comment: query /400 meaning the earlier version of query managerment. the manager made 8 queries to get to the desired data. normally she does this, and I run the convert command to get the sql equivalent.  RTVQMQRY. But when the query is doing breaks and totals on that, and summary level, the data is off. I prefer to get the exact data.

Comment: at any rate, all i want to do is make a stored procedure containing these 8 queries and then the crystal report  can run that.

Comment: It's technically possible to return multiple result sets from a stored proc, but that doesn't seem like a good way to get started. I'd suggest beginning by learning how to return just one of them first. Perhaps then continue making each of the 8 work separately. And finally make the step of combining them.

Comment: Query/400 and Query Manager (QM) are two different products. One is not the earlier version of the other. Also, QM can generate reports that include breaks and totals. But as @BuckCalabro notes in his answer, "breaks and totals" are not exactly "query" functions but instead are "reporting functions". Query/400 will generally only create those in a spooled report. Note that it's technically possible to generate 'break & total' values as part of a QM query **without** a report (even though QM can also put them into a spooled report just like Query/400).

Answer (score 2):

**Create a external stored procedure and call your CL program from there.**

`CREATE PROCEDURE mylib/sqlprocname
LANGUAGE CL MODIFIES SQL DATA
EXTERNAL NAME mylib/clprogname`

[Redbooks](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg245402.pdf)

[IT jungle article](http://www.itjungle.com/mgo/mgo080803-story01.html)

[SQL Reference on iSeries](http://194.196.36.29/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafz.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> I run the convert command to get the sql equivalent. RTVQMQRY. But
>   when the query is doing breaks and totals on that, and summary level,
>   the data is off. I prefer to get the exact data.

There is a terminology issue here that needs to be addressed.  The 'exact data' - level breaks and totals - that you see with Query/400 is a formatted report; the sort of thing that you would do with program logic in an RPG program.  It is very important that you understand this part: Query/400 is manipulating the raw data.

You can put business logic inside a stored procedure, but you will have to write that code yourself.  Since you are using Crystal Reports, why don't you put that business logic inside the Crystal Report?